# CSS android font-weight:lighter not working

Tags: android, css, fonts

I know there are already some fixes but none of them seem to work.

I want to use "Helvetica Neue" with `font-weight:300` on my site. It all looks good on Desktop but as soon as I switch to android, there seems to be no light fonts.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/cipef/3/edit) you can see my test at jsbin.com . Feel free to edit around, on my Galaxy S3 and Nexus 4 the fonts all have the same weight.

As you can see I also tried to include roboto and set it to light but that didn't work either (used some more methodes but didn't want to make an extra H1 for every single one).

My testcase:

```
<h1 class="neue">Does not work</h1>
<h1 class="neueLight">Does not work</h1>
<h1 class="neueLighter">Does not work</h1>
```

with this CSS:

```
h1.neue {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.neueLight {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.neueLighter {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

### This worked (only with android 4.2+):

There seem to be no solution on how one can use a specific light font without a font-face import or using google Fonts.

The solution is using `sans-serif-light` as first font-family font.

The best solution looks like this:

html:

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif-light,"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: You should include code for reproducing the problem, in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be no solution on how one can use a specific light font without a font-face import or using google Fonts.

The solution is using `sans-serif-light` as first font-family font.

The best solution looks like this:

html:

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif-light,"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

### Note: this only works with android 4.2+

Comment: This would work only if the system contains a font named `sans-serif-light` (or the browser recognizes that name as a nonstandard generic name)..

Comment: It works on android only (tested winPhone and iPhone on real website) so it might not be the optimal solution for everyone - but as I just needed a fix for android without including another font, it worked for me

Comment: Does not work on my Android. The only thing that seems to work here is the `font-weight` setting, and causes a *normal* (regular) weight to be used, overriding the default bold face for `h1`. So I think you would get the same result, normal (not light) weight by simply setting `h1 { font-weight: normal }`. The `font-family` setting affects browsers depending on font repertoire available, but I’m pretty sure that the `sans-serif-light` part is always ignored.

Comment: May I ask which device you have and which version of android? All test devices I have worked fine (Galaxy S3 and 4 , nexus4 - also several browser)

Comment: I’m using LG-P875, Android 4.1.2. With your code, I see the text in the default font of the device, in normal weight – the same I get with setting just `h1 { font-weight: normal }`. – I found some info on `sans-serif-light` as being available and denoting Roboto Light, from Android 4.1 on, but the references seem to deal with applications, not web pages in the default browser.

Answer (score 4):

Helvetica Neue is not available on most devices, including Android (which has a small set of installed fonts).

Regarding Roboto, you seem to be asking for weight 100, but your `link` element only takes weight 300 into use. And you are referring to the font only in WOFF version, which is not supported by many Android versions.

Comment: I changed that one to the google webfont link (see html) but that does not change anything

Comment: I changed the order of the roboto font (set it as first) and now it seems to work fine! The problem is that I don't really want to use any google fonts - can I just use the "system font" of android with font-weight:300 ?

Comment: @Hauke, I don’t think any system font in Android has any weight other than 400 or 700.

Comment: It has! See my solution, all you need to use is sans-serif-light - but thanks for this, I wouldn't come to this solution without any 'loud thinking'

Answer (score 0):

use font-weight:100

also make sure your font supports different font weight

Comment: Why should he use 100 when he wants 300?

Comment: Not only I want 300, not 100 - this does not work either (you may try it on my js-bin sample)